# jQuery: first callback isn't fluent (slidedown effect)

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, slidedown

I know this probably must be a newbie question, but since I don't know much about jquery I have to ask it here:

I have a  element that has to toggle different content on clicking on different buttons.Now i'll post here just how I call my javascript:

> onclick="javascript:gotoSubonderdeelmenu(this);"

This gets the div element, and with this i'll get the right id for the content to show.
Now my jQuery code:

```
function gotoSubonderdeelmenu(obj) {
    displaySubMenu(obj.id);
}



function displaySubMenu(niveauId) {
    $.get("submenu.htm", { niveau : niveauId }, function(data) {
        $('#submenu').html(data);
        $('#submenu').slideDown('slow',function(){
            $('#overzicht').fadeTo(500,0.25,function(){});
            $('#terugknop').show();
        });
    });
}
```

It always just fluently slides down like you would expect, **except the first time it's being called.**

Anyone got a clue on how to solve this?

Comment: What *is* it doing, just appearing?

Comment: @Nick Craver: it just appears and in an instant pushes everything instantly down to get enough space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the content so it slides/expands from nothing, like this:

```
$.get("submenu.htm", { niveau : niveauId }, function(data) {
    $('#submenu').html(data).hide().slideDown('slow',function(){
        $('#overzicht').fadeTo(500,0.25,function(){});
        $('#terugknop').show();
    });
});
```